# React Typescript - generate HTML to PDF or print designated section

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pdf

I'm building an application using React Typescript. I want the ability to generate a PDF (client side). On button click I want to create a PDF with set state values found on the page along with styling.

I'm trying to find the easiest way to approach this. Whether it be converting HTML to PDF or using the `Control + P`and having destination set to `Save as PDF`.

I don't want to print or generate a PDF from the whole component just the section that's wrapped around my class `printThis`.

What method or component would you recommend?

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class WebappProps extends React.Component<WebappProps, {}> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    async printForm(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        //Either generates form with info within "printThis" class and keeps styled
        //or
        //Opens up print popup(Control + P) with destination set to "Save as PDF"  
    }


  public render(): React.ReactElement<WebappProps> {
        return (
            <div className={styles.printThis}>
                <div className={`${styles.flexWrap} ${styles.flexEnd}`}>
                    <div className={`${styles.singleField} ${styles.halfFlex}`}>
                        Some stuff here
                    </div>
                    <div className={`${styles.singleField} ${styles.halfFlex}`}>
                        More stuff here: {this.state.item1}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 

            <button onClick={this.printForm.bind(this)}>Print</button>              
        );      
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done something similar to generate pdf reports of forms. I have used html2canvas to convert component to image and jsPDF to convert image to pdf. You can find those packages in npm.

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: I believe this solution will generate a PDF that is purely an image. So no text, and as you zoom in it will get blurry at some point.

Comment: Purely client side in the browser, something like MrRio/jsPDF where you generate the PDF manually using an API is the only solution that (should) keep text and vector. This would work if your HTML is not too complicated and you can maintain the mapping. So if you just need a subset of HTML to PDF, then you might find a 3rd party API solution, like above, that supports what you need. Otherwise, I am not aware of any pure client side, general HTML to PDF conversion. Those exist, but are all server side. If you are OK with server side, then update your question.

Comment: @Ryan thanks for this. It honestly doesn't even have to be HTML to PDF if there is a way to generate or create a PDF from client side that's all I'm looking for. Every option I found doesn't work. Let me take a look at `MrRio/jsPDF`